# Image blurred when capturing from tablet

Tags: android, android-camera, tablet

When I capturing the image by using camera in the android mobile phones, The image received is accurate/good quality. But if I capturing the image from tablet android 7.0, Then the image received is blur.

Please tell me how to resolve this issue?

**My Image code is :**

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                intent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING", 2);
                startActivityForResult(intent, PIC_CAPTURED);
```

Comment: can you post both pictures somewhere?

Comment: i am using that image in my app and after that send it to server

Comment: Try to use `MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT`  with `MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`.

Comment: i am using but not work in tablet

Comment: image is blured on preview screen in tablet

Comment: maybe the camera is out of focus?

Comment: when i am using the device camera it is working fine but from app it is blured

Comment: You are not capturing an image. You will only get a thumbnail.

Comment: `when i am using the device camera it is working fine but from app it is blured` ??? Pretty unclear where you are talking about. What comes from app that does not come from camera?

Comment: @RaviRajput Can you attach the both images?